# Is this a rose runner?

Tags: identification, roots, roses

Recently I noticed a few clusters of these new growths near a rose bush, and one a few feet away. Just based on the several inch distance I would guess they are rose runners. But the rose itself doesn't have nearly this level of clustered growth.

It's in zone 7, eastern US and there have been some unseasonable warm days that maybe triggered this, but still not sure if it's the rose at all.

[image: cluster of new growth]

[image: bigger cluster of new growth]

Comment: The photos show what looks to me like a violet or other similar low-growing plant.